# Class accepts varying arguments Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would a class accept varying arguments?
For example, if I had a class like this

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides
```

If I call this as Shapes(3), the sides will be 3 AKA a triangle.

How would I do this:
If I wanted to just call it as a Shape() with no arguments, it would automatically make the Shape() have self.sides = 4. AKA a square

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a default argument:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, sides=4):
        self.sides = sides
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'object' is another class then Shape would copy object like this:

```
class object():
    self.bla = 'bla'
class Shape(object):
    ...
```

else do this:

```
class Shape():
    ...
```